# Problem with Rstudio and other similar programs. (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, rstudio

I installed Rstudio after R and i checked that R works well. The problem is that when i start the program only see a window so big (Pic). And the window continue over desktop.

[image]

Rstudio terminal output:

[image]

Comment: What are your desktop environment, video driver and RStudio version? Do you have any error output in the terminal while trying to run RStudio as `rstudio`?

Comment: GNOME 3, nvidia-driver-435(proprietary,tested), the version of Rstudio is the last (1.2.5033), no i dont have any error but when i wrote rstudio on terminal works and the icon too now, and the problem was solved, but how the problem was solved i mean with icon didnt work in the past but when i  wrote rstudio on terminal  the problem was solved adn the icon works now . U know why? btw tx for help.

Comment: @N0rbert srry again but now dosent work i ll upload my output of rstudio wrote in the terminal

Comment: This looks as a problem between Qt (used by RStudio) and Nvidia OpenGL driver. I do not own any modern Nvidia card with nvidia-driver-435. What Nvidia card model do you have? If your card is not too new, you can try to switch the Nvidia driver to previous version by using 4-th tab of `software-properties-gtk` and retry to run RStudio.

Comment: @N0rbert is a RTX2080 super windforce OC 8GB GDDR6